# Interpreting the Sign of the Jacobian Determinant

Tags: jacobian, orientation

The sign of the Jacobian determinant of a two-dimensional transformation tells us if the transformation is *locally orientation-preserving* (if it's positive) or *locally orientation-reversing* (if it's negative).

> Is there a similar interpretation of the Jacobian determinant for a three-dimensional transformation?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818415/jacobian-matrix-and-determinant-relation-to-orientation

Comment: Thanks, @user. So, to clarify, if the Jacobian is positive in some neighborhood, the transformation preserves (right hand) orientation of a triple of vectors, and if it's negative, this triple changes the orientation. Correct?

Comment: If you define a right-handed triple of vectors $(a,b,c)$ by $(a\times b)\cdot c>0$ then yes.